# iframe com problemas na versão mobile e resolução alterada

Tags: html, css, mobile, iframe

Estou desenvolvendo meu primeiro site e estou tendo alguns problemas com uma página; especificamente a página de Portfólio.

Pra criar um menu de catálogo, usei um iframe com as imagens e criei um menu pra direcionar os articles, como pode ser visto um exemplo abaixo.

```html
<section id="catalogo">
            <nav id="menucatalogo">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="catalogo.html#convitesDig" target="catalogo">Convites Digitais</a></li>
                    <li><a href="catalogo.html#convitesConv" target="catalogo">Convites Convencionais</a></li>
                    <li><a href="catalogo.html#logotipos" target="catalogo">Logotipos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="catalogo.html#video" target="catalogo">Edição de Vídeo</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <iframe src="catalogo.html" name="catalogo" id="frame-catalogo"></iframe>
        </section>
```

Na versão desktop fica perfeito, igual nas imagens, assim como fica perfeito também no DevTools Device Toolbar do Opera e Chrome (usei os dois navegadores como base), mas na versão mobile mesmo deu problema... o iframe não fica cortado igual deixei no comando CSS e os textos (principalmente os botões de menu principal) ficam distorcidos (vide abaixo)
[image: Versão Desktop]
[image: Versão Devtools Device Toolbar]
[image: Página sendo executada num iPhone 7]

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@font-face {
    font-family: 'printclearly';
    src: url("../_fonts/printclearly.otf");
}

section#catalogo {
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
}

nav#menucatalogo {
    display: block;
}

nav#menucatalogo ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 120px;
}

nav#menucatalogo li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #373737;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    margin: 0 -5px 0 0;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
    font-family: printclearly, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

nav#menucatalogo li:hover {
    background-color: darkgray;
    border-bottom: 2px white solid;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}

nav#menucatalogo a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
}

nav#menucatalogo a:hover {
    color: #000000;
}

iframe#frame-catalogo {
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
    border: none;
}
```

Pode ser culpa do 000WebHost? Fiz alguma coisa errada?
Desde já agradeço!